# `qdbus` cannot be called in Kubuntu Saucy

Tags: kubuntu, 13.10, qdbus

I just booted a fresh Kubuntu 13.10 ISO in a virtual machine and tried to run `qdbus` and got an error that not a single Qt installation was found:

```
qdbus: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

The `qdbus` package is installed. How can I get it to work without installing `qdbus-qt5` like I did on my main machine, where it broke a little differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default qdbus-qt5
```

It seems the qdbus package got split out. Not sure the qt5-default install is needed though, but it worked for me.

References:
http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=107875
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qttools-opensource-src/+bug/1215905

Comment: Hmm, that would install a lot of dependencies. Is that really needed?

Comment: I installed `qt4-default`, and it works now!